# How to permanently save a macro in LISP (sbcl)

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

Lets say i define a macro

```
(defmacro foo(x)
    (print x))
```

Now i want to be able to always load this macro in all my lisp files in future where should i save this macro?

Comment: for eg in C/C++ i can easily do this by making a custom header file and saving that in /usr/local/include for example (or add my function in one of the standard headers (-:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every CL implementation has an init file it calls on start. For SBCL that is ~/.sbclrc. Usually also quicklisp has some setup code in there if you installed quicklisp.

So you could add a line:

```
(load #P"path/to/your/macro/file.lisp")
```

And it'll get loaded each time you start SBCL.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a library.

A library can contain any number of definitions, not only macros.

The de facto standard way to define *systems* (which is a more general term for libraries, frameworks, and applications — units of software) is to use ASDF.

Let's say that you put your macro into a lisp file:

```lisp
;;;; my-util.lisp

(in-package cl-user)

(defpackage my-util
  (:use cl))

(in-package my-util)

(defmacro foo (x)
  `(whatever ,x etc))
```

Then you put that under a directory that is known to ASDF.  One useful directory for that is `~/common-lisp/`, so let's use `~/common-lisp/my-util/`.  In the same directory, put the system definition file:

```lisp
;;;; my-util.asd

(in-package asdf-user)

(defsystem "my-util"
  :components ((:file "my-util")))
```

Now you can load this utility into any lisp interaction, e. g. on the repl:

```lisp
CL-USER> (asdf:load-system "my-util")
```

Or in a different system:

```lisp
;;;; my-application.asd

(in-package asdf-user)

(defsystem "my-application"
  :depends-on ("my-util")
  ...)
```

In the case of utility libraries, you often want to `use` their package so that you don't need to package-qualify the symbols.

If you want things that only work on your computer (like shortcuts for your REPL use or one-off scripts), you can sometimes get away with adding things to your implementation's init file.